# Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"'

Tags: java, mysql, jersey, openshift

I am trying to deploy my Jersey project on openshift. I have implemented this apple class to test the error in the another class since I guess the problem is with the establishing the database connection. in the Tails log I found this error:

> Connecting to databaseâ€¦
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"'.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

```
package org.busTracker.serverSide;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class Apple {

   //I modified my credients.
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/serverside";
    String user = "adminBjv5a4k";
    String password = "7tvPb1Bx3v8j";

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {

        Connection conn = null;  
        try {    
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
          System.out.println("Connecting to database…");    
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,password);    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
          e.printStackTrace();    
        } finally {    
          if (conn != null) {    
            try {    
              conn.close();    
            } catch (SQLException e) {    
              // ignore    
            }    
          }    
        }   

        return "Hello, from apple class   14.05.15 11:35!";
    }

}
```

**Edit:** I added the following to the try block after DriverManager.getConnection():

```
  Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
  for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
      System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                        envName,
                        env.get(envName));
  }
```

I have tried the following but I am still getting the same error:

- This solution: https://forums.openshift.com/mysql-51-jboss-app-numberformatexception-mysql-url And add the following jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/serv‌​erside but nothing changed.
- "jdbc:mysql://127.10.310.130:3306 /serverside"; This values are from the phpmyadmin of the app.

Comment: it is interpreting `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT` as a String not as is's value

Comment: Review [env vars](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html). Maybe all yout problem is that your forgot the '$' so access the `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT` system var.

Comment: @Fran: I have added it but it did not solve the problem and I am getting the same `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"`

Comment: check if system variable OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT is set

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20610185/2139691

Comment: @FranMontero: How can I check whether the vairiable is being set? I tried Ricardo solution but nothing is being output. Please see my edit question.

Comment: @Ricardo: I tried with your link to check whether the env variable is being set but nothing is being output. Please check my question code. Have I set it at the right postion?

Comment: @MrPencil don't you know the port where mysql is lostening?

Comment: @FranMontero: Is not it the port in the phpmyadmin `3306`?

Comment: @MrPencil try with the final value: `"jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:3306/serverside"`

Comment: I have tried this solution before, when I set the value `3306` for port then I am getting `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` then I set the server ip in the phpmyadmin for `$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` then I am getting `Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`.

Comment: I have pinged the ip address of the server and I am getting packets back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is because of this line

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/serverside";
```

to get the environment variable, you need to use the method `System.getEnv().get("[the variable name]")`. So, in your case, the host variable should looks like this

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://" 
              + System.getenv().get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") 
              + ":" 
              + System.getenv().get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT") 
              + "/serverside";
```

by the way, your edit does not work because the application  already throws an exception before it execute the code. so, to make it work, you need to put it *`before`* the `DriverManager.getConnection()` function.

Comment: Aha it works now thank you :) I am using the tail files of openshift in eclipse to track what happens on openshift server but I have to request openshift from the browser to see the output in tail files if I request it from the `POSTMAN`  Chrome or `HttpRquester` firefox I can not  say any output in the tail files just the rendering in HTML since my another class has a POST method so I cant request it from the browser and I need a tool to do it but nothing happening in the tail files! when I user POSTMAN or HttpRequester? can you give me any advice how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: I just have to fix this problem `The superclass “javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet” was not found on the Java Build Path` which I saw when I changed to the Jboss perspective and I am getting output now anyway thanks again since this problem costed my 3 days hard work over 30 hours.

Comment: I'm not quite understand what are you trying to ask. And, I'm not very familiar with those two tools. But, usually I use jquery to create and test my rest function and the log I use `rhc tail -a [apps name]` it should shows  what happen in log file.

Comment: Please can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933408/openshift-does-not-react-on-interval-of-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could replace those variables as below .

```
       <property name="url"                                                                                                              
      value="jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
       yourdatabasename" />

       can be replaced as below.

     <property name="url"  
    value="jdbc:mysql://127.12.97.2:3306/yourdatabasename"
    />
```

jdbc:mysql://127.12.97.2:3306/yourdatabasename"The IP address and the portnumber can be obtained from the openshift phpmyadmin page and they are usually displayed on top of the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions but it didn't solve my problem. So anyone still getting that exception, try this.
The value stored in environment variable **$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST** is something like

> 'jdbc:mysql://adminuname:adminpass@127.02.0.1:3306/appname'

. Therefore, using that value to create the url for DriverManager.getConnection() gives us the exception. 
Instead try to know the value stored in **$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST** and then hard code the url into a String variable without that username and password. Something like this

> 'jdbc:mysql://127.02.0.1:3306/appname'

For me it started working after making this modification. All other environment variables can be used as it is.

[I found this solution here.](https://youtu.be/07sV6CiDqqM)